# How to select textbox values in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've set textbox as multiline, and now whenever I mouse click on muliple items of that textbox, it is shown selected. May I know how can I do this?

Comment: This is a very unclear question.

Comment: Agreed... do you want to know if something IS "highlighted" within the textbox, and if so, WHAT it is?... or do you want it to automatically select (hightlight) ALL the text when a user tries to get focus to that control for editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select or highlight the entered text/content of a Text-Box control, then use the following method:

`textBox.Select();`

Please see if this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm seeing the words select and item, I think maybe you are wanting to use a [listview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) (set to detail view) instead of a textbox.  It would allow you to have items on separate lines and be able to select them by clicking on them.